# Logo design critique for web developer

Tags: logo, critique, branding

This is a logo for a web developer of responsive websites.
He was thinking about using square brackets (as he is a programmer) or using his initial of his first name "h".
He is also wanting advice on whether to use use his name or is it better to use a company name. He will be working on his own and would like to work with small businesses.
Thanks.
[image]

Comment: wether to use use his name or a company name - this is definitely off-topic here as it's up to him to decide that and everyone will have a different opinion.
On the logo question, please check the [guidelines for critique questions](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/681/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work) and [edit] your question to add the missing details and make it answerable.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's about the colors, but something in this screams to me of politics

Answer (score 1):

This question is really subjective, but for what it's worth, here are my opinions . . .

- I think the logos are too busy, and need to be simplified somewhat
- The colours are a rather garish/in-your-face. The bottom one is more subdued though
- The whole look is quite angular/boxy, giving a kind of construction
  industry feel. I'm thinking plumber, metal fabricator, brick layer,
  floor tile manufacturer, architect, etc. This may or may not be desirable.
- The word "WEB" is so small and condensed that it will virtually be unreadable at smaller sizes, even more so since it's also rotated vertically.

Note: These are just my opinions, so feel free to ignore them totally.

As for using one's name or a company name, I think that's up to your client. I wouldn't be happy giving advice on this - since there may be legal implications depending on the jurisdiction.